# How to get the Event Listeners added to DOM Element in Java

Tags: java, dom

I can add a EventListener to a DOM Element with:

```
Element elt = document.getElementById(elementId);
EventTarget t = (EventTarget) elt;
t.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

but how can I get the list of Event Listeners assigned to that Element? EventTarget has only methods to add and remove them.

Comment: I think this is not possible to achive what you are looking for.

Comment: @wastl can you please explain me why they did not provide this?

Comment: I think one of the reasons is, so that one cannot unregister all registered observers.  I also think its "nobody elses businness" who is listening to changes. I cannot think of another one but I'm sure there are some more.